# PowerBI show all items in a table

Tags: powerbi

I have a table  with the following data

[image]

This produces the summary report below

[image]

From the summary I want to drill through to detail eg  item “a” will be

[image]

But when I try to create a table to be drilled into in Power BI it is giving the summary

[image]

When I drill through to "a" I have one row instead of six rows, same with b, c  ect. Any idea on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I doubt that you can do that actually. What you need to do, is to add different columns to the detailed table and therefore slice it another time.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting, that you do not drill to a certain row, but a certain class. Therefore on your detail page, you are working with the exact dataset slice you want, despite it might not look like it.